# Replace the last instance of a string in a field in an SQL subquery

Tags: sql

I have a list of customer salutations separated by a ','. I need to replace the last instance of the ',' with an '&'. Here is the final part of my code:

```
MAIL AS ( SELECT DISTINCT ACC_NO, 
, STUFF((SELECT ', '+SALUTATION
FROM CUST C2 
WHERE C1.ACC_NO = C2.ACC_NO
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS SALUTATION
FROM CUST C1)
```

The output of `SELECT * FROM MAIL` looks like this:

```
ACC_NO > SALUTATION
1000 > MRS SMITH, MRS JONES, MRS BLOGGS
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
ACC_NO > SALUTATION
1000 > MRS SMITH, MRS JONES & MRS BLOGGS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try To use a Combination Between :

[SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187748.aspx)

[CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186323.aspx)

[REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186862.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query for replacing the last , by &

```
SELECT REVERSE(
                STUFF(
                       REVERSE(SALUTATION)
                       ,CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(SALUTATION))
                       ,1
                       ,' &'
                      )
              ) 
FROM MAIL
```